# Spark : Find preceding value form the list

Tags: databricks

i'm struggling to find the preceding item from a list based on a variable.
Let say i have a list

```
date = ['20190501','20190502','20190503','20190507','20190508']
```

and i have another variable stored as:

```
start_date = ['20190507']
```

what i would like to find is the preceding value of the `start_date` and store it as `previous_date` which i'm calling further down in my code.

So in this case, the previous_date would be `['20190503']`.

In another case if my `start_date = ['20190503']` and the list is the same, the 
previous_date would be `['20190502']`.

Comment: What does this have to do with pyspark?

Comment: I meant to say in spark.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python for loop, how to find next value(object)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929039/python-for-loop-how-to-find-next-valueobject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a List structure so you can use its [built-in methods](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) like `index`.  It returns a 0-based index of the first item equal to its *x* argument, something like:

```
%py
date = ['20190501','20190502','20190503','20190507','20190508'] 

start_date = ['20190507']

## So in this case, the previous_date would be ['20190503'].
x = ['20190501','20190502','20190503','20190507','20190508'].index(start_date[0])

date[x - 1]
```

My results:

[image: My results]